# How to plot cumulative distribution function?

Tags: python, probability-density

I'm pretty new to Python.

Density Function:

[image]

How can I determine the cumulative distribution function? And how can I plot the density function and the cumulative distribution function?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Assuming you are talking about normal distributions, you can find out how to plot pdf here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138308/503835 and also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9379432/503835 including the cdf.

Comment: ok cool, thanks.
But how can I formulate that x is between 0 - 1 and 1-3. I tried something like this:
def cdf(x):
    if x>=0 and x<1:
        return(1/2*x)
    elif x>=1 and x<=3:
        return(1/4*x)
    else:
        return(0)

Comment: @MisterData Not sure what you're getting at with the 0-1 and 1-3 'formulation'. If you want to calculate the probability that x will be less than or equal to some value y then you could probably just use the scipy norm function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.htmll)