# How to plot cdf in python

Tags: python, scipy, cdf

I have got an sorted array of integers and I want to plot a Cumulative Distribution Function for it. However , the nature of data is uncertain , so I think I cannot use any predefined library for it.

So to implement it , I have used interpolation function (scipy.interpolate).
I am doing it like this :

```
def plot_cdf(self,x,y,):
        tck = interpolate.splrep(x,y,s=0)
        y = interpolate.splev(x,tck,der=0)
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x,y)
        xlabel("Percentage")
        ylabel("Unavailability slot duration")
        plt.show()
```

Can it be improved??? Is there any predefined function for it????

Comment: What do you mean with "the nature of data is uncertain"? Also, what's the point of `xnew` here, since it remains equal to `x`?

Comment: hey this code is a snippet and I mean data can/cant fit into any distribution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to plot empirical cdf in matplotlib in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209362/how-to-plot-empirical-cdf-in-matplotlib-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You plot functions with `plot`, which is what you are using.

Comment: yup, i m using matplotlib.pyplot.plot function