# numpy/scipy equivalent of R ecdf(x)(x) function?

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy

What is the equivalent of R's `ecdf(x)(x)` function in Python, in either numpy or scipy? Is `ecdf(x)(x)` basically the same as:

```
import numpy as np
def ecdf(x):
  # normalize X to sum to 1
  x = x / np.sum(x)
  return np.cumsum(x)
```

or is something else required?

**EDIT** how can one control the number of bins used by `ecdf`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209362/how-to-plot-empirical-cdf-in-matplotlib-in-python) should help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try these links:

[statsmodels.ECDF](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF.html)

[ECDF in python without step function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006520/ecdf-in-python-without-step-function)

Example code

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(0,5, size=2000)

ecdf = ECDF(data)
plt.plot(ecdf.x,ecdf.y)
```

Comment: Is this not possible with scipy?

Answer (score 34):

The OP implementation for `ecdf` is wrong, you are not supposed to `cumsum()` the values. So not `ys = np.cumsum(x)/np.sum(x)` but `ys = np.cumsum(1 for _ in x)/float(len(x))` or better `ys = np.arange(1, len(x)+1)/float(len(x))`

You either go with `statmodels`'s `ECDF` if you are OK with that extra dependency or provide your own implementation. See below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF
%matplotlib inline

grades = (93.5,93,60.8,94.5,82,87.5,91.5,99.5,86,93.5,92.5,78,76,69,94.5,
          89.5,92.8,78,65.5,98,98.5,92.3,95.5,76,91,95,61)


def ecdf_wrong(x):
    xs = np.sort(x) # need to be sorted
    ys = np.cumsum(xs)/np.sum(xs) # normalize so sum == 1
    return (xs,ys)
def ecdf(x):
    xs = np.sort(x)
    ys = np.arange(1, len(xs)+1)/float(len(xs))
    return xs, ys

xs, ys = ecdf_wrong(grades)
plt.plot(xs, ys, label="wrong cumsum")
xs, ys = ecdf(grades)
plt.plot(xs, ys, label="handwritten", marker=">", markerfacecolor='none')
cdf = ECDF(grades)
plt.plot(cdf.x, cdf.y, label="statmodels", marker="<", markerfacecolor='none')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: ECDF comparison]

Answer (score 7):

The [ecdf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/ecdf) function in R returns the empirical cumulative distribution function, so the have exact equivalent would be rather:

```
def ecdf(x):
    x = np.sort(x)
    n = len(x)
    def _ecdf(v):
        # side='right' because we want Pr(x <= v)
        return (np.searchsorted(x, v, side='right') + 1) / n
    return _ecdf

np.random.seed(42)
X = np.random.normal(size=10_000)
Fn = ecdf(X)
Fn([3, 2, 1]) - Fn([-3, -2, -1])
## array([0.9972, 0.9533, 0.682 ])
```

As shown, it gives the [correct 68–95–99.7% probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) for normal distribution.

Answer (score 6):

This author has a very nice example of a user-written ECDF function: [John Stachurski's Python lectures](http://johnstachurski.net/lectures/more_numpy.html). His lecture series is geared towards graduate students in computational economics; however they are my go-to resource for anyone learning general scientific computing in Python.

**Edit**: This is a year old now, but I thought I'd still answer the "Edit" part of your question, in case you (or others) still fin it useful.

There really aren't any "bins" with ECDFs as there are with histograms. If G is your empirical distribution function formed using data vector Z, G(x) is literally the number of occurrences of Z <= x, divided by len(Z). This requires no "binning" to determine. Thus there is a sense in which the ECDF retains all possible information about a dataset (since it must retain the entire dataset for calculations), whereas a histogram actually loses some information about the dataset by binning. I much prefer to work with ecdfs vs histograms when possible, for this reason.

Fun bonus: if you need to create a small-footprint ECDF-like object from very large streaming data, you should look into this "[Data Skeletons](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1288830)" paper by McDermott et al.

Comment: The link is now broken. The author moved his python lectures to: http://quant-econ.net/py/index.html

Comment: The new link is also broken. Maybe this is the new (hopefully permanent) link? https://python.quantecon.org/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

[SciPy 1.11](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release/1.11.0-notes.html#scipy-1-11-0-release-notes) finally gained a built-in [`scipy.stats.ecdf(sample)` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ecdf.html).

For a given `sample` one-dimensional array-like object, e.g., a list, the function returns an object `cdf` that represents the estimated, i.e., empirical cumulative distribution function for that sample as well as an object `sf` that represents the empirical survival function for that sample.

The question asks for an equivalent of R's `ecdf(x)(x)`. Assuming that `x` is meant as the actual sample in both cases, the equivalent using the new SciPy function would be `scipy.stats.ecdf(sample).cdf.probabilities`.
Assuming that `x` is only the actual sample in the first case and the second should actually be the function parameter of the estimated cdf, then the equivalent would be `scipy.stats.ecdf(sample).cdf.eval(x)`.

Comment: Good points, thank you! For the time being I did skip a more practical usage example, as I do not yet have my hands on a SciPy version recent enough to contain the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- c(10, 20, 50, 40, 40, 30, 60, 70, 80, 90)
# Define a function to compute the ECDF
ecdf_func <- function(data) {
     Length <- length(data)
     sorted <- sort(data)
     ecdf <- rep(0, Length)
     for (i in 1:Length) {
          ecdf[i] <- sum(sorted <= data[i]) / Length
      }
      return(ecdf)

 }
ecdf <- ecdf_func(data)
print(ecdf)
```

Output:
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.6 0.5 0.5 0.3 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0

```
# With stats library
library(stats)

ecdf_fun <- ecdf(data)
ecdf_ <- ecdf_fun(data)
print(ecdf_)
```

Output:
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.6 0.5 0.5 0.3 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0

Comment: our answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center