# Extracting/Exporting the Data of the Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function in R (ecdf)

Tags: r

I use R to calculate the ecdf of some data. I want to use the results in another software. I use R just to do the 'work' but not to produce the final diagram for my thesis.

### Example Code

```
# Plotting the a built in sampla data
plot(cars$speed)
# Assingning the data to a new variable name
myData = cars$speed
# Calculating the edcf
myResult = ecdf(myData)
myResult
# Plotting the ecdf
plot(myResult)
```

### Output

```
> # Plotting the a built in sampla data
> plot(cars$speed)
> # Assingning the data to a new variable name
> myData = cars$speed
> # Calculating the edcf
> myResult = ecdf(myData)
> myResult
Empirical CDF 
Call: ecdf(myData)
 x[1:19] =      4,      7,      8,  ...,     24,     25
> # Plotting the ecdf
> plot(myResult)
> plot(cars$speed)
```

[image]

[image]

### Questions

**Question 1**

How do I get the raw information in order to plot the ecdf diagram in another software (e. g. Excel, Matlab, LaTeX)? For the histogram function I can just write

```
res = hist(...)
```

and I find all the information like

```
res$breaks
res$counts
res$density
res$mids
res$xname
```

**Question 2**

How do I calculate the inverse ecdf? Say I want to know how many cars have a speed below 10 mph (the example data is car speed).

### Update

Thanks to the answer of user777 I have more information now. If I use

```
> myResult(0:25)
 [1] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.08 0.10 0.12 0.18 0.22 0.30 0.38
[15] 0.46 0.52 0.56 0.62 0.70 0.76 0.86 0.86 0.88 0.90 0.98 1.00
```

I get the data for 0 to 25 mph. But I do not know where to draw a data point. I do want to reproduce the R plot exactly.

**Here I have a data point every 1 mph.**

[image]

**Here I do not have a data pint every 1 mph. I only have a data point if there is data available.**

[image]

### Solution

```
# Plotting the a built in sample data
plot(cars$speed)
# Assingning the data to a new variable name
myData = cars$speed
# Calculating the edcf
myResult = ecdf(myData)
myResult
# Plotting the ecdf
plot(myResult)
# Have a look on the probability for 0 to 25 mph
myResult(0:25)
# Have a look on the probability but just where there ara data points
myResult(unique(myData))
# Saving teh stuff to a directory
write.csv(cbind(unique(myData), myResult(unique(myData))), file="D:/myResult.txt")
```

The file `myResult.txt` looks like

```
"","V1","V2"
"1",4,0.04
"2",7,0.08
"3",8,0.1
"4",9,0.12
"5",10,0.18
"6",11,0.22
"7",12,0.3
"8",13,0.38
"9",14,0.46
"10",15,0.52
"11",16,0.56
"12",17,0.62
"13",18,0.7
"14",19,0.76
"15",20,0.86
"16",22,0.88
"17",23,0.9
"18",24,0.98
"19",25,1
```

Meaning

[image]

**Attention:** I have a German Excel so the decimal symbol is comma instead of the dot.

Comment: One useful idiom to keep in mind that helps to figure out what is happening is to call the function `ecdf(x)` with the data as an argument: `ecdf(x)(x)`. You may want to supplement it with some additional x-values (e.g. one to the left of the sample).

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I do not get it yet what f(x)(x) means. But I will try it later.

Comment: You call a function `g` of a variable `x` by `g(x)`. Now `ecdf(x)` - the output of the function `ecdf` - is *itself* a function. So you call the function `ecdf(x)` by passing it an argument: `ecdf(x)(x)`.

Comment: I see - great. Never saw this syntax before. Cool.

Comment: There's an example of it [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792552/numpy-scipy-equivalent-of-r-ecdfxx-function)

Comment: Hi Glen_b - I have read it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `ecdf` is a *function*, among other object types. You can verify this with `class(myResult)`, which displayes the S4 classes of the object `myResult`.

If you enter `myResult(unique(myData))`, R evaluates the ecdf object `myResult` at all distinct values appearing in `myData`, and prints it to the console. To save the output you can enter `write.csv(cbind(unique(myData), myResult(unique(myData))), file="C:/Documents/My ecdf.csv")` to save it to that filepath.

The ecdf doesn't tell you *how many cars* are above/below a specific threshold; rather, it states the *probability* that a randomly selected car from your data set is above/below the threshold. If you're interested in the *number of cars* satisfying some criteria, just count them. `myData[myData<=10]` returns the data elements, and `length(myData[myData<=10])` tells you how many of them there are.

Assuming you mean that you want to know the sample *probabilities* that a randomly-selected car from your data is below 10 mph, that's the value given by `myResult(10)`.

Comment: Thanks! And how can I exactly reproduce the plot with another software? I would be happy if I would have a csv file or something similar.

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe I did not describe my wish exact enough, I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks - that's almost what I need ;). I edited the question. In the R plot there in not every 1 mph a data point because in the data the points are not every 1 mph.

Comment: Great - thanks a lot! I will include the solution in the question so that others have just to look in one place.

Comment: What do I have to do to get an upvote for a question around here? :)

Comment: I see. What would then be the appropriate stackexchange for that kind of questions?

Comment: Haha - great. Before I posted the question I googled 'stackoverflow R statistic' and I landed here. But that's my fault. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

As I see it, your main requirement is to reproduce the jumps at each `x` value. Try this:

```
> x <- c(cars$speed, cars$speed, 1, 28)
> y <- c((0:49)/50, (1:50)/50, 0, 1)
> ord <- order(x)
> plot(y[ord] ~ x[ord], type="l")
```

[image: Resulting plot]

The first 50 (x,y) pairs are tyhe beginnings of the jumps, the next 50 are the ends, and the last two give you starting and ending values at $(x_1-3,0)$ and $(x_{50}+3,1)$. Then you need to sort the values in increasing order in $x$.

Comment: PS - But you could do this just as easily in other software, i.e. just save the x values, import them ino Excel, say, and do the equivalent of this using spreadsheet formulas and sorting.