# Empirical Distribution Function in Python better ways or formuals

Tags: python, probability, empirical-distribution

I want to know if there is a better, more accurate ECDF in python (for a single vector) or in general to use than mine. this is my current -

```
x = np.sort(X)
y = np.arange(1, len(x) + 1) / float(len(x))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792552/numpy-scipy-equivalent-of-r-ecdfxx-function/15792672?

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209362/how-to-plot-empirical-cdf-ecdf