# How to simulate new values without normality assumption?

Tags: python, numpy, random, normal-distribution, montecarlo

I have the following list:

```
series=[0.6, 4.1, 0.6, 6.7, 9.2, 7.6, 5.5, 0.9, 3.8, 8.4]
```

the `mean` of `series` is 4.74 and its `np.std` equals : 3.101

I want to generate 1000 observations from `series` so I used the following method:

```
>>> series_1000=np.random.normal(4.74, 3.101, size=(1000))
>>> series_1000
>>> array([ 3.43395217,  6.60462489,  5.27316166,  4.20429521,  4.76772334,
        8.04441319, -0.6967243 ,  0.53378519,  2.1736758 ,  9.96333279....
```

**Problem**

The above method seems to be good, however it works under the assumption that `series` is `normally` distributed.

**Goal**

My goal is to find a way of simulating values without any assumption regarding the original `series`.

Any help from your side will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can [bootstrap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383376/sampling-from-empirical-distribution) from the [empirical cdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792552/numpy-scipy-equivalent-of-r-ecdfxx-function).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Can you please add more details about this in an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a uniform distribution is better suited for your needs, you can use:

```
(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=1000) * 3.101) + 4.74
```

Or inside a convenience function:

```
def generate_values(mean, std, size=1000):
    return(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=size) * std) + mean
```

Comment: Thanks @Edu , I think this works under the assumption that `series` is uniformly distributed, although I search a method without any assumption

Comment: You cannot sample a number from an undefined distribution. The uniform distribution is however the less biased choice, so I would go for that if you don't know anything about the original distribution