# How to plot in CCDF with a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matplotlib

I can very well plot CDF and CCDF when the data is in one column. But I am a little clueless how to plot a CDF or CCDF when the data is in the below given format. The pairs in round brackets `()` are the node pairs. The values in square brackets `[]` are the occurrence value and the number in between eg: `7` are the frequency. We don't have consider the frequency, only the occurrence values.

Input data format, They are millions of rows with lot of values between the square braces (`[]`).

```
('4503', '656') 7 [2473.0, 35.0, 235.0, 157.0, 505.0, 45.0, 1303.0] 
('2105', '674') 1 [2584.0] 
('5139', '1086') 1 [1488.0] 
('3690', '2034') 6 [1009.0, 1108.0, 132.0, 447.0, 157.0, 466.0] 
('3867', '1982') 1 [1134.0]
```

I have to plot the CCDF of the data which is between the square braces (`[]`) all together and not separately. I am not understanding how do I read the data between between the square braces and plot it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what each of the numbers mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mainly to put the input data to the right format:

1. step: Parse the input file for the data you need, namely the values between the square brackets: This can easily be done with regular expressions using the re module from the python standard lib. Write them all space delimited to a text file.
2. step: assign all these values to a fast numpy array and plot them like described here: [Read file and plot CDF in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575869/read-file-and-plot-cdf-in-python)

Comment: If I am using `re` module to parse the input the pair from the round brackets and those from square brackets get mixed and it is really a mess to identify what is what.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply finding the index of the `[` and `]`, slicing out the data line by line and parsing it to a list using `ast.literal_eval` and appending it to the main list.

```
import ast
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

file_data = """('4503', '656') 7 [2473.0, 35.0, 235.0, 157.0, 505.0, 45.0, 1303.0] 
('2105', '674') 1 [2584.0] 
('5139', '1086') 1 [1488.0] 
('3690', '2034') 6 [1009.0, 1108.0, 132.0, 447.0, 157.0, 466.0] 
('3867', '1982') 1 [1134.0] """

data = []

for line in file_data.splitlines():
    data += ast.literal_eval(line[line.find('['):line.find(']')+1])
```

Once you have done the above, you should be able to plot the CDF as follows :

```
# Building an array of uniform x points ranging from 0 to the max(data)
X  = np.arange(0,max(data), max(data) / len(Y))

# Convert data to a numpy array
Y  = np.array(sorted(data))

# Normalizing data to yield a proper PDF vector
Y /= Y.sum()

# CDF can be obtained by the `np.cumsum` method:
Yc = np.cumsum(Y)

# Plot Y vs X
plot(X,Y,color="green" )

# Plot the CDF
plot(X,Yc,color="red"   )

# Display the plot
show()
```

The following is obtained for the above data :

[image]

Comment: This looks like it should work. I am a little confused to understand but I shall check it with full data and reply back. Thanks !!

Comment: I changed this `file_data = np.loadtxt('Input_File')`  But I get this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_line.py", line 5, in <module>
    file_data = np.loadtxt('Input_File')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 796, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ('785',`

Comment: load the entire data file as a string in the `file_data` variable. Use `f = open('Input_File'); file_data = f.read(); f.close()` and proceed as described above ! See if that helps ...