# Calculate the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, statistics, scipy

How can I calculate in python the [Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)?

I want to calculate it from an array of points I have (discrete distribution), not with the continuous distributions that, for example, scipy has.

Comment: How about using [`numpy.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)?

Comment: To use `numpy.cumsum` I believe you first need to calculate the PDF, which is an overhead.

Comment: You are looking for [ECDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function). @DrV provided you a simple version. It is also available in [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF.html).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

(It is possible that my interpretation of the question is wrong. If the question is how to get from a discrete PDF into a discrete CDF, then `np.cumsum` divided by a suitable constant will do if the samples are equispaced. If the array is not equispaced, then `np.cumsum` of the array multiplied by the distances between the points will do.)

If you have a discrete array of samples, and you would like to know the CDF of the sample, then you can just sort the array. If you look at the sorted result, you'll realize that the smallest value represents 0% , and largest value represents 100 %. If you want to know the value at 50 % of the distribution, just look at the array element which is in the middle of the sorted array.

Let us have a closer look at this with a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create some randomly ddistributed data:
data = np.random.randn(10000)

# sort the data:
data_sorted = np.sort(data)

# calculate the proportional values of samples
p = 1. * np.arange(len(data)) / (len(data) - 1)

# plot the sorted data:
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.plot(p, data_sorted)
ax1.set_xlabel('$p$')
ax1.set_ylabel('$x$')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.plot(data_sorted, p)
ax2.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax2.set_ylabel('$p$')
```

This gives the following plot where the right-hand-side plot is the traditional cumulative distribution function. It should reflect the CDF of the process behind the points, but naturally, it is not as long as the number of points is finite.

[image: cumulative distribution function]

This function is easy to invert, and it depends on your application which form you need.

Comment: Neat! Thank you for the answer. I don't know if I should create a new question for this but, what if my data has N dimensions? (for the purpose of the example lets say 2)

Comment: How do I get a function that I can use? Your answer only plots.

Comment: This `np.linspace(0, 1, len(data))` is cleaner than the `1. * arange(len(data)) / (len(data) - 1)`

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie to get this as an actual function, you can use interpolation: `f = lambda x: np.interp(x, p, data_sorted)`. Then you can `f(0.5)` for example, to get the median.

Comment: @charmoniumQ: I prefer `linspace` as well but it's worthy to mention it's good practice to use `np.linspace(0, 1, len(data), endpoint=False)` or `np.arange(len(data)) / len(data)`, otherwise it's not an unbiased estimator of CDF. I like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11692365/7964098) with detailed explanation.

Comment: This will give incorrect results in case there are duplicates in the list of samples. E.g., consider `data_sorted = [0,0,1,2,2]`, then you'll have multiple values in p for a given sample. Ideally it should be a one-one mapping.

Comment: why do we need the 1. * for line
p = 1. * np.arange(len(data)) / (len(data) - 1)

Comment: Why don't you just do statistics.median if f(0.5) is all you need?

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you know how your data is distributed (i.e. you know the pdf of your data), then [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) does support discrete data when calculating cdf's

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.randn(10000) # generate samples from normal distribution (discrete data)
norm_cdf = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x) # calculate the cdf - also discrete

# plot the cdf
sns.lineplot(x=x, y=norm_cdf)
plt.show()
```

[image]

We can even print the first few values of the cdf to show they are discrete

```
print(norm_cdf[:10])
>>> array([0.39216484, 0.09554546, 0.71268696, 0.5007396 , 0.76484329,
       0.37920836, 0.86010018, 0.9191937 , 0.46374527, 0.4576634 ])
```

The same method to calculate the cdf also works for multiple dimensions: we use 2d data below to illustrate

```
mu = np.zeros(2) # mean vector
cov = np.array([[1,0.6],[0.6,1]]) # covariance matrix
# generate 2d normally distributed samples using 0 mean and the covariance matrix above
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=mu, cov=cov, size=1000) # 1000 samples
norm_cdf = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x)
print(norm_cdf.shape)
>>> (1000, 2)
```

In the above examples, I had prior knowledge that my data was normally distributed, which is why I used `scipy.stats.norm()` - there are multiple distributions scipy supports. But again, you need to know how your data is distributed beforehand to use such functions. If you don't know how your data is distributed and you just use any distribution to calculate the cdf, you most likely will get incorrect results.

Comment: I don't get the point of having vector `x` sampled from normal distribution. Vector `x` rather be `linespace` to plot the parametric version of `cdf` you used from `scipy.stats`. Anyway the OP ask for non-parametric `CDF`, he is asking for discrete but he most likely meant `ECDF` which is non-parametric.

Answer (score 20):

The **empirical cumulative distribution function** is a CDF that jumps exactly at the values in your data set. It is the CDF for a **discrete distribution** that places a mass at each of your values, where the mass is proportional to the frequency of the value. Since the sum of the masses must be 1, these constraints determine the location and height of each jump in the empirical CDF.

Given an array `a` of values, you compute the empirical CDF by first obtaining the frequencies of the values. The numpy function `unique()` is helpful here because it returns not only the frequencies, but also the values in sorted order. To calculate the cumulative distribution, use the `cumsum()` function, and divide by the total sum. The following function returns the values in sorted order and the corresponding cumulative distribution:

```
import numpy as np

def ecdf(a):
    x, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    cusum = np.cumsum(counts)
    return x, cusum / cusum[-1]
```

To plot the empirical CDF you can use `matplotlib`'s `plot()` function. The option `drawstyle='steps-post'` ensures that jumps occur at the right place. However, you need to force a jump at the smallest data value, so it's necessary to insert an additional element in front of `x` and `y`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_ecdf(a):
    x, y = ecdf(a)
    x = np.insert(x, 0, x[0])
    y = np.insert(y, 0, 0.)
    plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-post')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig('ecdf.png')
```

Example usages:

```
xvec = np.array([7,1,2,2,7,4,4,4,5.5,7])
plot_ecdf(xvec)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[7,1,2,2,7,4,4,4,5.5,7]})
plot_ecdf(df['x'])
```

with output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For calculating CDF for array of discerete numbers:

```
import numpy as np
pdf, bin_edges = np.histogram(
   data,        # array of data
   bins=500,    # specify the number of bins for distribution function
   density=True # True to return probability density function (pdf) instead of count
   )

cdf = np.cumsum(pdf*np.diff(bins_edges))
```

Note that the return array `pdf` has the length of `bins` (500 here) and `bin_edges` has the length of `bins+1` (501 here).

So, to calculate the CDF which is nothing but the area below the PDF distribution curve, we can simply calculate the cumulative sum of bin widths (`np.diff(bins_edges)`) times `pdf` using Numpy `cumsum` function

Comment: I think that instead of *bins_count* you meant *bin_edges* on the last line of code, resulting in: ```cdf = np.cumsum(pdf*np.diff(bin_edges))```.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative pandas solution to calculating the empirical CDF, using `pd.cut` to sort the data into evenly spaced bins first, and then `cumsum` to compute the distribution.

```
def empirical_cdf(s: pd.Series, n_bins: int = 100):
    # Sort the data into `n_bins` evenly spaced bins:
    discretized = pd.cut(s, n_bins)
    # Count the number of datapoints in each bin:
    bin_counts = discretized.value_counts().sort_index().reset_index()
    # Calculate the locations of each bin as just the mean of the bin start and end:
    bin_counts["loc"] = (pd.IntervalIndex(bin_counts["index"]).left + pd.IntervalIndex(bin_counts["index"]).right) / 2
    # Compute the CDF with cumsum:
    return bin_counts.set_index("loc").iloc[:, -1].cumsum()
```

Below is an example use of the function to discretize the distribution of 10000 datapoints into 100 evenly spaced bins:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10000))
cdf = empirical_cdf(s, n_bins=100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(cdf.index, cdf.values)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_discrete_cdf(values):
    values = (values - np.min(values)) / (np.max(values) - np.min(values))    
    
    values_sort = np.sort(values)
    values_sum = np.sum(values)
    
    values_sums = []
    cur_sum = 0
    for it in values_sort:
        cur_sum += it
        values_sums.append(cur_sum)

    cdf = [values_sums[np.searchsorted(values_sort, it)]/values_sum for it in values]
    return cdf
```

```py
rand_values = [np.random.normal(loc=0.0) for _ in range(1000)]
_ = plt.hist(rand_values, bins=20)
_ = plt.xlabel("rand_values")
_ = plt.ylabel("nums")
```

[image]

```py
cdf = get_discrete_cdf(rand_values)

x_p = list(zip(rand_values, cdf))
x_p.sort(key=lambda it: it[0])

x = [it[0] for it in x_p]
y = [it[1] for it in x_p]

_ = plt.plot(x, y)
_ = plt.xlabel("rand_values")
_ = plt.ylabel("prob")
```

[image]