# OpenTurns Error when trying to use kernel build

Tags: python

I'm getting the following error when I try to build my kernel.

[Openturns error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWHs1.png)
Can anyone help?

Comment: Add the error as code. See [tour], [ask].

Comment: Add both errors within the question and not as link please. Otherwise I am afraid some will soon delete the question

Comment: unfortunately I can't because I don't think I have the rep to do it within the question :(

Comment: you have to indent with 4 space and copy past your errors. For more info see [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build only takes a Sample object. You have to convert your numpy array:

```
import openturns as ot
import numpy as np
sample = ot.Sample(np.array([(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0)]))
```

For the conversion to happen, your data need to have the proper shape: `(n_sample, dimension)`

In this example, we have 3 sample and the dimension is 2.