# How to use markers with ECDF plot

Tags: python, seaborn, google-maps-markers, ecdf

In order to obtain a ECDF plot with seaborn, one shall do as follows:

```
sns.ecdfplot(data=myData, x='x', ax=axs, hue='mySeries')
```

This will give an ECDF plot for each of the series `mySeries` within `myData`.

Now, I'd like to use markers for each of these series. I've tried to use the same logic as one would use for example with a [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), as follows:

```py
sns.lineplot(data=myData,x='x',y='y',ax=axs,hue='mySeries',markers=True, style='mySeries',)
```

but, unfortunately, the keywords `markers` or `style` are not available for the `sns.ecdf` plot. I'm using seaborn 0.11.2.

For a reproducible example, the penguins dataset could be used:

```py
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
sns.ecdfplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", hue="species")
```

Comment: Hi @JohanC, so what I'm trying to do is to use markers instead of flat lines, in my ECDF plot. But again, even if the curve would look unreadable ( which depends of course on the curves; in my case is totally possible ), how could one do it? I have colleagues that are color blind and the use of markers would be of help ...

Comment: Aside for the answer from @JohanC, you may consider creating your own ecdf plot directly with matplotlib, which would also allow you to use the `marker`, `linestyle` and other plot parameters. [Plotting all of your data: Empirical cumulative distribution function](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/projects/2019-07-10_statistical_thinking_1/2019-07-10_statistical_thinking_1.html#Plotting-all-of-your-data:-Empirical-cumulative-distribution-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate through the generated lines and apply a marker. Here is an example using the penguins dataset, once with the default, then using markers and the third using different linestyles:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15, 4))

sns.ecdfplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", hue="species", ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Default')

sns.ecdfplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", hue="species", ax=ax2)
for lines, marker, legend_handle in zip(ax2.lines[::-1], ['*', 'o', '+'], ax2.legend_.legendHandles):
    lines.set_marker(marker)
    legend_handle.set_marker(marker)
ax2.set_title('Using markers')

sns.ecdfplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", hue="species", ax=ax3)
for lines, linestyle, legend_handle in zip(ax3.lines[::-1], ['-', '--', ':'], ax3.legend_.legendHandles):
    lines.set_linestyle(linestyle)
    legend_handle.set_linestyle(linestyle)
ax3.set_title('Using linestyles')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: ecdfplot with markers or linestyles]

Comment: Thanks for this! One detail only, there is no match between color and marker. For example: `Gentoo` would be `+` or `green`?
On the other hand, I think there might be a simpler solution hopefully using `kwargs` to access matplotlib under the hood (as one would do with `sns.lineplot`). I'll keep looking.
Nevertheless, thanks for this! It gives me a hint... I'll have a look at it ...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It seems the legend is in a reversed order compared to the lines. I updated the code. Can you test with your data?  I really think currentlly there isn't an easier way to change the markers.

Answer (score 4):

- As noted in the documentation for [`seaborn.ecdfplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.ecdfplot.html), other keyword arguments are passed to [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot), which accepts [`marker`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_marker) and [`linestyle / ls`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle)

  - `marker` and `ls` accept a single string, which applies to all `hue` groups in the plot.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('penguins', cache=True)

sns.ecdfplot(data=df, x="culmen_length_mm", hue="species", marker='^', ls='none', palette='colorblind')
```

[image]

### Calculate ECDF directly

- An option which allows for using [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) or [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), is to directly calculate `x` and `y` of the ECDF.
- [Plotting all of your data: Empirical cumulative distribution functions](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/projects/2019-07-10_statistical_thinking_1/2019-07-10_statistical_thinking_1.html#Plotting-all-of-your-data:-Empirical-cumulative-distribution-functions)

```py
def ecdf(data, array: bool=True):
    """Compute ECDF for a one-dimensional array of measurements."""
    # Number of data points: n
    n = len(data)
    # x-data for the ECDF: x
    x = np.sort(data)
    # y-data for the ECDF: y
    y = np.arange(1, n+1) / n
    if not array:
        return pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
    else:
        return x, y
```

#### `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`

```py
x, y = ecdf(df.culmen_length_mm)

plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', linestyle='none', color='tab:blue')
plt.title('All Species')
plt.xlabel('Culmen Length (mm)')
plt.ylabel('ECDF')
plt.margins(0.02)  # keep data off plot edges
```

[image]

- For multiple groups, as suggested by [JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc)

```py
for species, marker in zip(df['species'].unique(), ['*', 'o', '+']):
    x, y = ecdf(df[df['species'] == species].culmen_length_mm)
    plt.plot(x, y, marker=marker, linestyle='none', label=species)
plt.legend(title='Species', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

#### `seaborn.lineplot`

```py
# groupy to get the ecdf for each species
dfg = df.groupby('species')['culmen_length_mm'].apply(ecdf, False).reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)

# plot
p = sns.lineplot(data=dfg, x='x', y='y', hue='species', style='species', markers=True, palette='colorblind')
sns.move_legend(p, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]